# Html in a gridview

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview databound by a datatable. In one of the columns the people who enter the data put in the location of their facility and a link to their website in the same cell. Like:

```
Baltimore, MD <a href="www.location.com">Location</a>
```

How do I make it so the link is read as html?

gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="start_date" HeaderText ="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="end_date" HeaderText ="End Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sponsor" HeaderText ="Sponsor" />
         <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields ="sponsor_id"
             DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/topics/spirometry/sponsors.html#c{0}"
             HeaderText ="Sponsor Details"
             Text="Details"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="location" HeaderText ="Location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="region" HeaderText="Region" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="course_type" HeaderText ="Course Type" />
    </Columns>
```

They would be adding to the column bound to the location field.

## SOLVED

```
 <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="start_date" HeaderText ="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="end_date" HeaderText ="End Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sponsor" HeaderText ="Sponsor" />
         <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields ="sponsor_id"
             DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/topics/spirometry/sponsors.html#c{0}"
             HeaderText ="Sponsor Details"
             Text="Details"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="location" HeaderText ="Location" HtmlEncode="false"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="region" HeaderText="Region" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="course_type" HeaderText ="Course Type" />

    </Columns>
```

changed htmlencode to false.

Comment: You're allowing people to enter their website as an href link? Why not have them submit the URL then do that yourself. Letting people submit HTML is usually pretty dangerous.

Comment: I'm working on a system that is currently in place. That part is out of my control. @TimTroiano

Comment: Alright, what's your code for the table so far then? The PHP echo command works with HTML.

Comment: it's asp.net code the back end is in c# i'll add the code for my gridview in the original post